# How to programmatically open a time picker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, materialize, timepicker

I have a [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com) time picker element.
I'd need to have it linked to a hidden input field, and (1) to trigger the opening of the clock dialog programmatically, from the click of a button.
Also, (2) I'd need to intercept the time selection event.

Here is a sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified MaterializeCSS JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" id="mytimepickerelement" class="timepicker" class="validate">
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn timepicker" onclick="showtimepicker();">Set time</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showtimepicker() {
  // (1) TODO ON $('#mytimepickerelement')
}
function initializetimepicker() {
    $('.timepicker').pickatime({
        default: '0:00',
        fromnow: 0,
        twelvehour: false,
        donetext: 'OK',
        cleartext: 'Clear',
        canceltext: 'Cancel',
        autoclose: false,
        ampmclickable: false,
        aftershow: function(){},
        // (2) SOMETHING ELSE TODO TO INTERCEPT TIME SELECTION/MODAL CLOSURE EVENT
    });
}
$(document.ready(intializetimepicker));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve (1) and (2) and have the button working?

Comment: It helps if you have a [mcve]

Comment: https://codepen.io/jonvadillo/pen/zqVWXp seems to do the trick. I searched for MaterializeCSS timepicker trigger

Comment: Edited as suggested. Your liked code is not linked to a button.

Comment: It is linked to a label that can be styled as a button

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Use css to style the label as a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first I found it kind of strange. I simulated click on timepicker but nothing happens. So I delayed it in ~1ms and it works... I know it is weird solution but still it is solution.

Sample HTML:

```
<a onclick="ope();">adas</a>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
                        <label for="timepicker_ampm_dark">Time am/pm ( dark theme )</label>
                        <input id="timepicker_ampm_dark" class="timepicker" type="time"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Js/jq:

```
//Time Picker:
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
    default: 'now',
    twelvehour: false, // change to 12 hour AM/PM clock from 24 hour
    donetext: 'OK',
  autoclose: false,
  vibrate: true // vibrate the device when dragging clock hand
});

function ope(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('label').click();
  },1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with the timeout. Concerning (2), it is possible to intercept changes on the `input`, such as `$('#mytimepickerelement').on('change', function(){ /* do stuffs here */ });`